# String Replace operation in GWT 2.0.4

Tags: gwt, string

I am using GWT 2.0.4 and want to perform the trivial operation of replacing string. 
Something which can be done using java.lang in java, and since GWT doesn't support Java libraries and I want to avoid writing a JSNI, is there a way to do a string replace, Is there anything i am missing or might not knw?
Latest version of GWT,which is just an RC, 2.1 has a library called com.google.gwt.regexp which have something as simple as 
originalString.replace(Expression String, Replacement String)
but since it is RC, I cannot use it here, Any suggestions are appreciated and Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (any any `java.lang` method listed [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html)) works in GWT.

Furthermore, it's incorrect to say "GWT doesn't support Java libraries" -- GWT supports lots of Java libraries, and many that aren't immediately usable can be made GWT compatible with a little work.